# Forbid users to delete files on shared OneDrive folder

Tags: permissions, onedrive

If I share a folder in OneDrive with other users, I want them to be **allowed to add files**, but I do **not want the other users to be allowed to delete files**.
If possible, as owner of the the shared folder, I would like to still be able to delete files.

- If I give them only "Can View" permissions, they can not add the Folder to their OneDrive and can whether add nor delete files in the Folder, just download the folder.
- If I give them only "Can Edit" permissions, they can add the Folder to their OneDrive and add/delete files.

So I need the users I share the folder with, to be able to add the folder to their OneDrive, to add files, but not to be able to delete files.

Answer (score 2):

*Note:* ***This answer is with regards to the permissions on the local file itself.*  When I answered the question it was not clear to be they were talking about the permissions on the cloud copy of the file.**

Within the properties of the folder in question do the following:

1. Click `Security`
2. Click `Advanced`
3. Click on the *Principal* you wish to change the permissions for.
4. Click `Edit`

   [image]
5. Click 'Show Advanced Permissions`
6. Remove the `Delete` permission

[image]

4. Click `Ok`
5. Within the `Advanced Security Settings` window hit `Apply`
6. Close all Windows.

As an Administrator user you might have to remove the inheritance on the folder in order for the `View` button to change to an `Edit` button.  *For the purposes of this answer I copied and pasted the `Edit` button into my screenshot.*

*This approach can still be used.  If they cannot delete the local file, then the cloud copy, cannot be deleted (unless they go to the browser and delete it).*

Comment: I will test this. I thought I will be able to set these permissions online in the browser.

Comment: No i did not mean on the local machine, I did not see that my question can be interpreted that way. I will edit my question.

Comment: This is not the answer, it's about cloud.

Comment: @MaXi32 - This question was migrated after I submitted my answer.  I am not prepare to modify my answer from 3 and half years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test, but I've heard Microsoft recently(?) restricted the *edit* permissions for people without a Microsoft account to only add objects or update existing ones. ([source of my assumptions](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/168228-onedrive-prevent-delete-shared-items.html#post2077480)). People with a Microsoft account are still able to delete objects with the *edit* permissions.

### Restrict permissions to not be able to delete objects

It's possible, although a bit complicated to achieve permissions for people to be able to add and update but not to delete, as described by Microsoft Agent in the [Microsoft Community regarding OneDrive permissions](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/onedrive-link-sharing-not-allowing-user-to-delete/9de19ac7-1103-4def-96f0-a37ee6fd7242):

1. Create a new Permission Level

   1. On OneDrive, click on the gear icon and **OneDrive Settings**
   2. On the left, select **More Settings** and **Return to the old Site settings page** under *Can't find what you are looking for?* on the bottom of the page
   3. Open **Site permissions**
   4. In the ribbon, open the **Permission levels** under *Manage*
   5. Open the **Edit** permissions and below the form, click on **Copy Permission Level**
   6. Give your new level an appropriate name and a helpful description
   7. Remove all the *Delete* permissions, as well as *Manage Lists* in *List Permissions*
   8. Click on **Create**
2. Apply the new Permission Level

   1. Back on the OneDrive page, click on the ellipse/three dots next to the folder you want to share
   2. Click on **Manage Access** and select **Advanced**
   3. In the ribbon, click on **Grant permissions*
   4. Add the people/mail addresses in the popup (under *Invite people*) and optionally add some explaining text below.
   5. Click on **SHOW OPTIONS** at the bottom and select the Permission Level you just created
   6. **Share** your folder

This solution does not work with just creating a link to share, but it's not restricted to people having a Microsoft account. So, you're restricted to Microsoft sending the mails to the people you want to invite.

I didn't check whether it might be possible to add the people by Microsoft accounts, deselect the **Send an email invitation** and then create a *View* link to send to the people. I think that the people get also the *add* permission when signed in.